# How to start running a private blockchain with a custom genesis.json file on http://localhost:8545?

Tags: go-ethereum

I have ran the following command:

```
> geth --rpc --nat none --dev --ipcpath "geth.ipc" init genesis.json
```

My genesis.json file looks like this (taken from the docs at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network):

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "200000000",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "7df9a875a174b3bc565e6424a0050ebc1b2d1d82": { "balance": "300000" },
        "f41c74c9ae680c1aa78f42e5647a62f353b7bdde": { "balance": "400000" }
    }
}
```

How do I get this blockchain then running on http://localhost:8545?

Comment: geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545"
```